# Not able to file the record in the Firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new document , and it is not giving me error in the logcat, but it is not even creating it.

I checked the address and retrieved the required values , they are all correct.

Please let me know where I am wrong in the below code.

```
    db.collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments").document(commentId).collection("messageRoom").document(roomId).collection("messages")
            .add(chat)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    successCallback.onSuccess(documentReference);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    failureCallback.onFailure(e);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please let me see your (chat) Map.

Comment: And add Log.d("TAG",e.message); into your onFailure() Method.. then check Logcat to know what exactly happens when run the code

Comment: @AhmadDarwesh for time being it is resolved now, thanks anyways for your  concern,

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode all those variables (postId, commentId and roomId) from the reference? Does it work that way? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Btw, if you consider at some point in time to try another approach regarding a chat app, here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the tutorial reference, but I am working with java, and don't any basics of kotlin right now, but I saved the reference for future use.